# Random string generated with random spacing in between

Tags: python, random

I would like to create a pattern the contains uppercase letters and numbers, also random spacing in between
as OI00 XKB or IT IEEW 88 ... etc

I have started with this code it generate random code but the spacing is constant between as `{}{}{}{} {}{}{}`

**code**

```
def codeGen():
 return "{}{}{}{} {}{}{}".format(
        random.choice(common.LETTERS),
        random.choice(common.LETTERS),
        random.choice(common.DIGITS),
        random.choice(common.DIGITS),
        random.choice(common.LETTERS),
        random.choice(common.LETTERS),
        random.choice(common.LETTERS))
```

how I can apply randomness on `format`

Thanks, in advance

Comment: It's kinda gross, but you could throw a `random.choice([' ',''])` between each and a few more `{}` to your initial string.

Comment: So just add in `random.choice((' ', ''))` calls? How many spaces are we talking about here?

Comment: one space between each successive letters/ numbers.
maybe more space can occur but not successive spaces

Answer (score 0):

solved

```
def generate_code():

    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) +random.choice(string.digits)+ random.choice((' ', '')) for _ in range(random.randrange(2,5)))
```